# BigInteger.intValue()>1 giving incorrect boolean

Tags: java, math, while-loop, conditional-statements, biginteger

I am trying to convert a BigInteger number into binary. I use a while loop to reduce the BigInteger until it is equal to 1, taking the remainder as the loop runs.

The conditional for the loop is: (decimalNum.intValue()>1).

But the program only goes through the loop once and then thinks that the BigInteger is less/equal to 1 while in reality it is around 55193474935748.
Why is this happening?

("inBinary" is an ArrayList to hold the remainders from the loop.)

Here is the while loop:

```
while (decimalNum.intValue()>1){
      inBinary.add(0, decimalNum.mod(new BigInteger("2")).intValue()); //Get remainder (0 or 1)
      decimalNum = decimalNum.divide(new BigInteger("2")); //Reduce decimalNum
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot represent all `BigInteger` values as `int`, as `int` only goes up to 2b. I'm guessing `intValue` overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the binary string value of your `BigInteger`, you could just do

```
bigInteger.toString(2);
```

**EDIT** : As mentionned in the comments by @VinceEmigh, converting `BigInteger` to `int` might lead to overflow.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know BigInteger had a method for that.

Answer (score 8):

55,193,474,935,748 doesn't fit into an int: the largest int value is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, i.e. 2,147,483,647, which is much smaller. So you get an integer overflow.

This is explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29), BTW:

> Converts this BigInteger to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

If you want to compare a BigInteger to 1, then use

```
decimalNum.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0
```